# What is causing extra whitespace in Bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, dropdown

What is causing my dropdown to have extra whitespace? (Apologies for the screenshot)

[image]

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" 
                            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="caret">Snooze</span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <button class="dropdown-item">1 Hour</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

As far as I know there is nothing strange in my CSS files that would cause this. I am using Bootstrap4.

Comment: Use the DOM explorer in your browser and see what css is creating the margin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this code. I removed `<span class="caret"></span>` because it's not a valid class in bootstrap. I changed `btn-default` to other button, `btn-primary` in this case.

The most important error - look at `dropdown-menu`. You open `button` tag and close `li` so I changed that to `div` and it works nicely.

Check out Bootstrap Docs for more info here [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/dropdowns/).

```css
/*DEMO*/
body{padding:3rem}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Snooze</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-item">1 Hour</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML structure is wrong. Check what you have inside the `.dropdown-menu` element.

Instead of `<button class="dropdown-item">1 Hour</li>` use `<li class="dropdown-item">1 Hour</li>`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Snooze
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li class="dropdown-item">1 Hour</li>
  </div>
</div>
```